# Pymongo: Connecting to a replicaSet

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am connecting to replicaSet just fine using the below code.

Today morning, one of the 2 replicaSet instances that we have, went down.

Still when I used the below code, at some instance I got a connection to the crashed replicaSet, at others I got the connection to the running replicaSet.

Is there any way in which I can prevent getting connection to the crashed instance.

This is the code that I use:

```
    from pymongo import ReplicaSetConnection
    from pymongo import ReadPreference

    # assume I have defined the used variables
    db = ReplicaSetConnection('%s:%s' %(host, port), replicaSet=r_set)[db_name]
    db.read_preference = ReadPreference.SECONDARY_ONLY
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you maybe add some more info regarding your cluster?  For example if you only have 2 nodes, then there are issues when 1 goes down because there will not be a majority (see [these docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-internals/#replica-set-election-internals).)  I think this issue would be easier to diagnose if we could have some greater insight into the system that you are having the issue on.

Comment: @ACE : Sorry for the ignorance, I have 3 instances of mongodb running on separate servers (1 primary and 2 secondary). That day one of the secondary went down. Rest all was ok, the only thing that was weird to me was that, while it was down I could see queries coming in. Please let me know if I am missing some required detail.

Comment: @ACE One more thing (if it may help) that day the secondary crashed because it got too much behind the primary.